# How to create this hash on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, hash, windows-phone-8, cryptography, windows-phone

I'm working with the [Kraken API](https://www.kraken.com/help/api#general-usage) and to query the private methods I need to send a hash as a parameter. This is what their documentation says:

> Public methods can use either GET or POST.
>
> Private methods must use POST and be set up as follows:
>
> HTTP header:
>
> API-Key = API key
>
> API-Sign = Message signature using HMAC-SHA512 of
>   (URI path + SHA256(nonce + POST data)) and base64 decoded secret API
>   key
>
> POST data:
>
> nonce = always increasing unsigned 64 bit integer
>
> otp = two-factor
>   password (if two-factor enabled, otherwise not required)
>
> Note: There
>   is no way to reset the nonce to a lower value so be sure to use a
>   nonce generation method that won't generate numbers less than the
>   previous nonce. A persistent counter or the current time in hundredths
>   of a second precision or higher is suggested.

They also have a [PHP](https://www.kraken.com/help/api#example-api-code-php)/[Node.JS](https://www.kraken.com/help/api#example-api-code-nodejs)/[Python](https://www.kraken.com/help/api#example-api-code-python) example that creates the API-Sign hash. I am trying to port this code to C# for Windows Phone 8, but I encountered a big problem: the [HMACSHA512](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha512%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class isn't available for Windows Phone. I tried searching for alternatives that can create a HMAC-SHA512 hash, but couldn't find much. [HashLib](http://hashlib.codeplex.com/) isn't available for Windows Phone. [CryptSharp](http://www.zer7.com/software/cryptsharp) is, but I can't figure out how to add both a message and a password like PHP's [hash_hmac()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php) function allows. I also went searching for the algorithm/pseudo code for the HMAC-SHA512 algorithm to implement my own class but strangely enough I couldn't find it (does it have another name?).

Long story short, I need to convert this code in a Windows Phone 8 compatible piece of code that yields the same result:

```
if(!isset($request['nonce'])) {
    // generate a 64 bit nonce using a timestamp at microsecond resolution
    // string functions are used to avoid problems on 32 bit systems
    $nonce = explode(' ', microtime());
    $request['nonce'] = $nonce[1] . str_pad(substr($nonce[0], 2, 6), 6, '0');
}

// build the POST data string
$postdata = http_build_query($request, '', '&');

// set API key and sign the message
$path = '/' . $this->version . '/private/' . $method;
$sign = hash_hmac('sha512', $path . hash('sha256', $request['nonce'] . $postdata, true), base64_decode($this->secret), true);
$headers = array(
    'API-Key: ' . $this->key,
    'API-Sign: ' . base64_encode($sign)
);
```

The first part (till $sign = ...) looks pretty straightforward:

```
long nonce = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;

string postData = "nonce=" + nonce;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(otp))
{
    postData += "&otp=" + otp;
}
```

But when I get to the cryptography part, I get stuck due to the lack of libraries.

Comment: Someone mentioned on MSDN forums that they got HashLib to work on WP8. Have you tried that? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5409ed2f-ea75-46dc-937f-3111ce9ed2ca/hmacsha512-with-windows-phone-8

Comment: Tried that, and nope, it's not compatible with WP8. I'd have to rewrite their library in order to make it compatible. To be honest, cryptography is not really my specialty.

Comment: There is pseudo code on the [Wikipedia page about HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code#Implementation). It's not hard to implement. The choice of hash only influences the block size in the computation. And if in doubt, try the standard itself [which implements it for MD5 in C](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2104).

Answer (score -1):

This isn't likely to even compile, but it should give you the general idea..

```
byte[] uriPath = GetBytes(uriPathString);
byte[] nonceAndPostData = GetBytes(nonce + postData);

byte[] keyData = Convert.FromBase64String(apiKey);
string decodedKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(keyData);

byte[] result;
SHA512 shaM = new SHA512Managed();
SHA256 shaN = new SHA256Managed();
result = shaN.ComputeHash(nonceAndPostData);
result = shaM.ComputeHash(result + decodedKey);

static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: It's nice an all that you introduce the class `SHA512` and `SHA512Managed` in your code, but like I said: they aren't available in Windows Phone 8. That's the whole problem.

Comment: @LeonCullens You can take [open-source](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Security.Cryptography) SHA algorithm realization and as you saw HMAC is very simple logic on top of it.